# How to add syntax highlighting to a Linkedin Pulse post

Tags: javascript, css, syntax, linkedin-api

I know very little about web development.

I am trying to add code to a `linkedin` post, I tried `github Gist` but it does not work.

Is there a way or it is just impossible?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that it is still (as of 2017-11-27) not possible to directly include a GitHub Gist in an LinkedIn Pulse article, nor does it appear that there is any built in feature on LinkedIn for syntax highlighting of source code.

A common technique appears to be to take a screenshot of a Gist, embed the screenshot in the article, and have the screenshot link to the Gist.  That's a rather cumbersome technique that requires updating the article anytime the Gist changes, but it will work.

Details here:

https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/include-code-snippet-pulse-articles-florent-georges/

Comment: ended up doing to same thing, but still would like to keep this question open so in case things change in future someone can update over here.